# git worktree and resetting dropbox shared folder

Tags: git, dropbox, git-worktree

I have a project-repo that resides in my Dropbox folder. From there, I share it with my co-author, who does not use git.

```
home
├── Dropbox
    ├── project-repo
```

Co-author's dropbox account is full. Co-author erased a large file to save space, but a past commit included that file. Problem is that `.git` directory, which keeps the large file in the repo's history, remains too big.

I wish to follow the advice [here](https://discuss.ropensci.org/t/peace-between-git-and-dropbox-with-git-worktree/289), using `git worktree` to have a linked working tree project-repo-shared. This will be the new shared folder in Dropbox (it should not have a `.git` directory, and therefore be much smaller).

```
home
├── Dropbox
    ├── project-repo
    ├── project-repo-shared
```

The question is how to not create conflicts in my co-author's files on disk. Are these the steps I should plan to take?

(1) Un-share the project-repo folder in Dropbox (letting co-author know in advance)

(2) Do `git worktree add -b shared-in-dropbox ~/Dropbox/project-repo-shared`

(3) In dropbox.com, share new folder project-repo-shared with co-author

(4) after co-author's machine syncs the new project-repo-shared folder, he can delete project-repo, and voilà! (right?)

Better ideas much welcome!

Comment: The simplest solution would probably be if your colleague just used Git. That’s what it was made for.

Comment: True @mkrieger1. Obstacles: git easily scares off many people; and github does not like large files like the one causing trouble in my friend's dropbox...

Comment: Can your co-author's copy of the repo be a shallow clone, starting from after the large file was removed?

Comment: Thanks @Mort. That sounds promising. Can you elaborate on shallow clones?

Comment: https://www.perforce.com/blog/vcs/git-beyond-basics-using-shallow-clones